# Visual Studio fopen_s error

Tags: visual-studio, file-io

I tried to open a file with `fopen_s` in Visual Studio 2017

the code looks like

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    FILE*fp;
    fopen_s(&fp, "input.txt", "r,css=UTF-8");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

then i got a run time error which looks like:

> File:minkernel\crts\ucrt\inc\corecrt_internal_stdio.h Line:684
>
> Expression:("Invalid file open mode", 0)
>
> For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure,
>   see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts

Comment: "coded character set", not "cascading style sheets".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag is called `ccs` not `css`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    FILE*fp;
    fopen_s(&fp, "input.txt", "r,ccs=UTF-8");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```